# Reading a File and storing it into an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, integer

I need some help with reading the first line of input from a text file through an array and printing it.
My code now prints a huge number, which I'm not looking for.

My text file:

```
5
My first cat
csc221
My favorite
```

The code I have so far:

```
            FILE *myFile;
            char ar[1];


            myFile = fopen("‪mcPro1.txt", "r");

            fgets(ar,1,myFile);


            int x = atoi(ar);  //Convert it to a string

            printf("%d\n", ar);

            fclose(myFile);
```

Comment: `char a[1]` is a single character. That can't hold any useful C string data.

Comment: **On what operating system?** Linux (and POSIX) has [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), which for *small* files -a few gigabytes- could be more convenient (to be used with [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html); read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for more)

Comment: Otherwise, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), then the documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ...)

Comment: **Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler.** If you use  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Your code has [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of [**buffer overflow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Comment: I'm on Windows and using Code Block atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using fscanf. The code below was taken from [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/read-file) but I tried editing it to try your case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit() function
int main() {
    char ar[1];
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("mcPro1.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads text until newline is encountered
    fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", ar);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", ar);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want the size of your variable ar to exactly fit the size of the string being read, try looking up memory allocation, e.g., realloc(). Refer to [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```c
c = fgetc(myfile);
while(c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    c = fgetc(myfile);
}
```

Refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-print-contents-file/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create the right sized variable to contain contents of a file might include the following:

- Determine the file's size in bytes (the size of an single `char`)
- Create either a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) or use [dynamic memory allocation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/).

Following is an example, using the VLA method:  (avoids the need to free memory.)

```
unsigned long sizeInBytes = fsize(".\\‪mcPro1.txt")
char ar[sizeInBytes];
//Then fgets becomes:
fgets(ar,sizeInBytes,myFile);
```

Where `fsize(".\\‪mcPro1.txt")` could be defined as:

```
unsigned long fsize(char* file)
{
    if(!file) return 0UL;
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
    if(!f) return 0UL;
    if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) return 0UL;
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
}
```

The rest of your code should work as written as long as the contents of the file are convertible to an integer value.